# Module pattern defined in separate files

Tags: javascript

Is there a convenient approach to code organization, which allows to create a module pattern, but define its internally exposed functionality in separate files.

So, with a module below, can `SomeInternalObject2` be defined in another js file and still be accessible from the first file (assuming proper ordering of script files)?

```
var MyModule = (function(){
  function SomeInternalObject1(){..}
  function SomeInternalObject2(){..}
  return {
    this.publicFunction = function(){..}
  }
})();
```

**EDIT:** Perhaps I'm thinking about it in a wrong way. Code organization is a development-time concern. Require.js, module-loading, etc.. is a run-time concern.

Comment: Have you had a look at Require.js? The SomeInternalObject2 would not really be internal though. I don't think there's a way to to import js code into a scope (other than `eval`ing it...).

Comment: I have written my own import function that loads another module via `$.ajax` then `eval` it. It is like; `var Module = (function() { var AnotherModule = loadModule('AnotherModule'); ... })();` It is simple and might not be the perfect solution. Would like me to post the code as an answer, or it wouldn't fit your scenario?

Comment: @renatoargh, it would be interesting to see, but it doesn't quite fit. Maybe I'm thinking about it in a wrong way?

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig, I've taken a look. I think you're right - it not be internal.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at jTable (javascript). The author augments the main object from different files. It is not exactly what you are asking for, but the intention or goal seems similar. I might add code later.